# How do I print pdf files in c?

Tags: c, pdf

Im doing a small project on printing files through c.

I use linux as the Os. Everything works fine but I cant find  any solution on the pdf format. Is there any library I can use for this?

Comment: Not a bad question, but add what you tried till now. Have you found similar but not able to make it work?

Comment: There are libraries, you just must look. I needed to do something similar years ago, but I preferred to write my own code to generate LaTeX files so I could compile them with `pdflatex` command.

Comment: depends what your requirements are as @adripanico says, pdflatex can work or pstricks.  Or if you want lower-level rendering libraries check out libHaru or cairo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

1. You can write your own code to write the **PDF** file by learning pdf file structure
   [PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)
2. You can use an existing library like [Haru](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libharu/), [JagPDF](http://www.jagpdf.org/)

No. 1 is the hard way apparently but it's also fun in my opinion.

Comment: No. 1 is *definitely* advisable, as learning the background technique will teach a lot more than the dumb 'download lib / include lib / use lib' routine preferred by so many. (Only to come back here and complain, "Why can't I do *x* with library *y* when Adobe's Reference sez I can?")